# How to plot in a different style functions in a Table, based on a given condition

Tags: plotting

I struggle to find meaningful title.
A minimal example will easily clarify the problem.

Let's say I define a function such as

```
    f1[L_, n_, x_] := Mod[L, n]*x + x
```

and then issue

```
   Plot[Table[f1[100, n, x], {n, 1, 10}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

As expected I get four lines: the one with slope $1$, corresponding to the table indices $n = 1,2,4, 5,10$, one with slope $2$ for $ n = 3,9$, etc.

They are all plotted in the same colour.

How could I plot for example in dashed red, only the lines such that $\mod[L, n] = 0$ ?

Thanks

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[f1[100, n, x], {n, 1, 10}], {x, 0, 10}]` then set the `PlotStyle` to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am not so sure I understand. I found an example in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html, but I want to assign a specific PlotStyle to curves that satisfy a certain condition. I might have tens of curves, could certainly not assign manually. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[f1[100, n, x], {n, 1, 10}], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> 
  Table[If[Mod[100, n] == 0, {Dashed, Red}, Automatic], {n, 1, 10}]]`

Comment: like this one, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163384/plotstyle-based-on-if-condition, I see thanks a lot

Comment: For future reference (mine), I used this solution,  ````Plot[Evaluate@Table[f1[100, n, x], {n, 1, 10}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Table[ Which[Mod[100, n] == 0, {Dashed, Red}, 
    True, {Dashed, Blue}], {n, 1, 10}]] ````

Comment: You could also consider `With[{L = 100}, Plot[Table[Style[Mod[L, n]*x + x, If[Mod[L, n] == 0, Directive[Red, Dashed], Directive[Blue, Dashed]]], {n, 1, 10}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}]]`.

Comment: @Smerdjakov If you found a solution yourself, please post it as an answer to your question, so other users in future might find it more easily. Comments are not properly searchable and material of value should be preserved in an answer. Furthermore, self-answering is encouraged in this forum.