# Evaluation order and Tables - Errors when using Evaluate@Table

Tags: plotting, evaluation

following this question of mine [Conditional PlotStyle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163384/plotstyle-based-on-if-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1), I ran into another problem.

I fear it has to do with evaluation orders, as for example described in [Table and Evaluation Order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172417/table-and-evaluation-order), but I am totally unable to understand the subtlety.

Even recreating a minimum working example proved trickie. The following is sufficient to trigger a problem (although not exactly the same I witness, I hope the roots are the same).

A function is defined

```
  f2[x_, y_] := x^2 - y
```

and another two, the first using using `FindMinimum`

```
 g[y_] := FindMinimum[f2[x, y], x]

 f3[z_, n_] := g[z/n][[1]]
```

Now if I use

```
  Plot[Table[f3[z, n], {n, 1, 10}], {z, 0, 0.3}]
```

everything runs fine.

Yet, if I do

```
   Plot[Evaluate@Table[f3[z, n], {n, 1, 10}], {z, 0, 0.3}]
```

I get minimisation errors. In my original case I do get a plot, albeit a wrong one, compared to the correct results I get before using `Evaluate`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definitions to

```
f2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 - y;
g[y_?NumericQ] := FindMinimum[f2[x, y], x][[1]]
f3[z_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := g[z/n];
```

Now it works

```
  Plot[Evaluate@Table[f3[z, n], {n, 1, 10}], {z, 0, 0.3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This makes it "see" these functions with numerical arguments only, not symbolic, and hence these functions are called *when* the arguments has been bounded to the numerical values,  and not before.

Comment: One further modification I would do is to use `FindMinValue[]` in defining `g`.

Comment: @J.M. good idea. I did not want to modify the OP code itself now too much, since the issue was just the plotting problem. Just changed it to make the plot works.